# Delphi XE TValue.From(True) does not yield TValue boolean

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti, setvalue

I have a boolean field which I want to set using `MyField.SetValue(Self, MyValue)`. No matter what I tried, I keep getting typecast errors.

The problem is that MyValue always contains an ordinal and is not recognized as containing a boolean. I know that boolean is an enumeration, which is an ordinal, but it should still be possible to set boolean fields and properties using TValue.

I tried the following to initiate MyValue but every time `MyValue.IsOrdinal = True` while `MyValue.IsBoolean = False`:

1. `MyValue := TValue.From(True);`
2. `MyValue := TValue.From<Boolean>(True);`
3. `MyBool := True; MyValue := MyValue.From(MyBool);`
4. `MyBool := True; MyValue := MyValue.From<Boolean>(MyBool);`
5. `MyValue := True;`
6. `MyBool := True; MyValue := MyBool;`
7. `MyBool := True; TValue.Make(@MyBool, TypeInfo(Boolean), MyValue);`

Is there a way to get the TValue to accept that it contains a boolean i.s.o. an ordinal so that `MyField.SetValue(Self, MyValue)` will succeed?

Thanks in advance,

Decolaman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TValue) works fine with boolean values.

Check this sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

Type
  TAnyClass=class
   AField : Boolean;
  end;

Var
 Ctx       : TRttiContext;
 MyValue   : TValue;
 A         : TAnyClass;
 MyField   : TRttiField;
begin
  try
    Ctx:=TRttiContext.Create;
    A:=TAnyClass.Create;
    try
      MyField:=Ctx.GetType(TAnyClass).GetField('AField');

      MyValue:= MyValue.From(False);
      MyField.SetValue(A, MyValue);
      Writeln('The Value of AField Is '+BoolToStr(A.AField, True));

      MyValue:= MyValue.From(True);
      MyField.SetValue(A, MyValue);
      Writeln('The Value of AField Is '+BoolToStr(A.AField, True));
    finally
      A.Free;
      Ctx.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Indeed it does. I wrote a small test also for properties, and it works there. In my application however, it does not. When I find the problem, I'll post it here.

Comment: Apparently, in the next attempt to set a value with Rtti, the RttiField and the object to set it to mismatched, causing the typecast error.